# wamp - phpmyadmin (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I've created a database for learning purposes. 
For some reason phpmyadmin won't show the structure of the table values. Went to SQL and typed "DESCRIBE test", then an error message popped up:

```
#1 - Can't create/write to file'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\#sql9ec_133_6.MAI' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
```

I can't figure why would it try and create a file in that directory since this was the first time I've installed WAMP in this machine.

Answer (score 0):

AV firewall caused the issues with WAMP/phpmyadmin. After uninstalling and resetting firewall and network settings everything went back to normal.